# windows application having no dependency to install

Tags: visual-c++, language-agnostic, architecture, mfc, dependency-management

I want to implement windows desktop form application having no dependencies to install (e.g. framework, third-party etc).

In which technology I can achieve this?

Can i achieve this goal in C# Win-forms?

Answer (score 2):

You can build an MFC app that requires no installation (just copying the files to the target computer) by statically linking and/or deploying the Visual C++ runtime redist side-by-side.

As Arnon has answered, you can build a .Net app that requires no installation if you target a version of .Net that is pre-installed on your target operating system. This [blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os.aspx) lists the .Net versions included with each version of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

what version of windows are you targeting your application to ? different versions of windows have different versions of .NET (see [this link](http://www.msigeek.com/2390/what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-which-version-of-the-os) for details).

So basically, if you are looking for no installation you'd have to shoot for the lowest common denominator and/or ship multiple versions of your app. 
I understand that it isn't what you want but -If you do go with .NET it is usually better to ensure that the installer will install the right version of .NET if needed (see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4k032e1.aspx) for example)